# Одновременное звучание нескольких wav звуков

Tags: c#, wav

Пишу виртуальное пианино, необходимо каким-нибудь образом иметь возможность воспроизводить несколько звуков одновременно.

Это код который запускается по нажатию на кнопку:

```
    private void wk1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string SoundPath = @"путь до файла.wav";
            MainPlayer(SoundPath);
    }
```

Это метод из которого воспроизводится звуковой файл:

```
    private void MainPlayer(string path)
    {
        player.SoundLocation = path;
        player.Play();
    }
```

В данном виде, программа по нажатию на клавишу воспроизведения нового звука обрывает старый (если он был) и воспроизводит новый.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А какого типа переменная `player`, нам нужно догадаться самостоятельно?

Comment: SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен и как выше ответили неизвестно что за player.
Но попробуйте для каждого звука создать свой экземпляр player'a

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/165638)

Comment: @mymedia, почему?

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне кажется, это сообщение слишком короткое, не тянет на полноценный ответ — недостаточная проработка. Такое, скорее всего, должно быть комментарием.

Comment: @mymedia, а по-моему, это скорее всего верный ответ :) Для одновременного воспроизведения нужно по инстансу проигрывателя на каждый воспроизводимый звук - всё логично.

Comment: Когда оставлял этот ответ, у меня было недостаточно репутации для комментирования. Но поскольку мысль стоящая решил донести ее автору любым способом.